# Stack columns with Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to stack three columns like below on Power BI.
My example dataset is following:

| Processo | Finalidade 1 | Finalidade 2 | Finalidade 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maçã | Banana | Mamão |
| 2 | Banana |  |  |
| 3 | Mamão | Banana |  |

However, I would like that it stay like this:

| Processo | Finalidade |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Maçã |
| 2 | Banana |
| 3 | Mamão |
| 1 | Banana |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | Banana |
| 1 | Mamão |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |

I tried to transpose columns but I can't this result.

Comment: In power query, select the 3 Finalidade columns and unpivot them. This will result with something closer to your desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your input data and the hint in the comments I did it like that

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblData"]}[Content],
    Step1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Processo", Int64.Type}, {"Finalidade 1", type text}, {"Finalidade 2", type text}, {"Finalidade 3", type text}}),
    tblUnPivot = Table.ReplaceValue(Step1,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Finalidade 2"}),
    replaceValues = Table.ReplaceValue(tblUnPivot,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Finalidade 3"}),
    unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(replaceValues, {"Processo"}, "Attribut", "Wert"),
    sorted = Table.Sort(unpivot,{{"Attribut", Order.Ascending}, {"Processo", Order.Ascending}}),
    removeCol = Table.RemoveColumns(sorted,{"Attribut"}),
    renameCol = Table.RenameColumns(removeCol,{{"Wert", "Finalidade"}})
in
    renameCol
```

Result looks like

[image]

But the solution strongly depends on the naming of the columns *Finalidade 1* etc.

**PS** Another solution which is independet of the naming of the columns could look like that

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblData"]}[Content],
    Step1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Processo", Int64.Type}, {"Finalidade 1", type text}, {"Finalidade 2", type text}, {"Finalidade 3", type text}}),
    tblUnPivot = Table.ReplaceValue(Step1,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Finalidade 2"}),
    replaceValues = Table.ReplaceValue(tblUnPivot,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Finalidade 3"}),
    unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(replaceValues, {"Processo"}, "Attribut", "Wert"),
    addColumn = Table.AddColumn(unpivot, "colPos", each List.PositionOf(Table.ColumnNames(Step1),[Attribut])),
    #"Neu angeordnete Spalten" = Table.ReorderColumns(addColumn,{"Processo", "colPos", "Attribut", "Wert"}),
    removeCol1 = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Neu angeordnete Spalten",{"Attribut"}),
    sortRows = Table.Sort(removeCol1,{{"colPos", Order.Ascending}, {"Processo", Order.Ascending}}),
    renameCol = Table.RenameColumns(sortRows,{{"Wert", "Fianlidade"}}),
    removeCol2 = Table.RemoveColumns(renameCol,{"colPos"})
in
    removeCol2
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace null with some characters. Unpivot other columns. Replace characters with null. Remove extra column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,null,"~~~",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Finalidade 1", "Finalidade 2", "Finalidade 3"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns1" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Replaced Value", {"Processo"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Other Columns1","~~~",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Value"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value1",{"Attribute"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```